# Issue with root owner of Azure Account (somehow got modified and I don't have access). How can I clean-up?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I used personal e-mail as “Microsoft Identity” to sign-up for Azure Free Trial. My expectation is my e-mail ID is the root login for my account and associated identity is the root owner, and I think that was the case initially. Later, I deployed an Azure AD Tenant with a different name, turns out a bizarre pseudo-e-mail ID (UPN) became root owner of my parent account which I don’t have access for. Now I can’t delete subscriptions or the unwanted UPN. How can I reset my account to start from clean slate? One way is to use a different e-mail ID and get started with new account. I am wondering if some one can provide steps to perform clean-up and restart with same old e-mail ID / identity as root owner. Azure support plans start @ $29.00/month and I am trying to avoid that.

Another symptom, I can't cancel supscription. It asks me to use contact owner, and that happens to be that bizarre very long email looking UPN which I can't use for login as those credentials aren't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [contact Azure Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) Team and raise a subscription ticket which is free for further help.

They can help you to manage your subscription owner and credit card / billing information from the backend.